# After upgrading my website to PHP 8.0 PEAR send() function stopped working! Status code 500

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I have got a website that was perfectly sending SMTP mail using the PEAR Mail package.

After I upgraded my domain to the PHP 8.1 version CGI, the function

`$smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);` stopped working!

Status code 500

the log file error is:
include_once(Net/SMTP.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/......./pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php

Therefore I tried to install it but the error this time was:

pear/Net_SMTP is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.10.0 install failed

and in the Chrome Developer Tools "network" response there is not a RESPONSE ! Empty!
Any idea?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error code that can mean anything. You need to check the web servers error log to find the actual error message and add it to your question.

Comment: I know that it sound strange but when i try to set "display_errors = on" in the php.ini file, I don't get any error but the email is not sent

Comment: If you get 500, then there is a fatal error thrown somewhere. As far as we know, it could just as easily be a faulty server config/htaccess and not PHP. Make sure you have error reporting set to E_ALL as well. Did you check the error log as well? Without the actual message, we would just be guessing, which isn't constructive for anyone. Also remember that you need to restart the web server (if apache) or PHP-FPM (if you're using that) after changing your php.ini

Comment: include_once(Net/SMTP.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/......./pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php

Comment: pear/Net_SMTP is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.10.0
install failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. Basically, after I upgraded my domain to the PHP 8.1 version, PEAR stopped working. The error I detected was:

include_once(Net/SMTP.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/......./pear/share/pear/Mail/smtp.php

Net_SMTP was installed but the server could not get the file BECAUSE OF
PEAR CODE !!!!

You have to change the path requests that are present in different files in PEAR:

```
 include_once __DIR__."/../Net/SMTP.php";//include_once 'Net/SMTP.php';

require_once __DIR__."/../PEAR.php" //require_once 'PEAR.php';
require_once __DIR__."/../PEAR.php"; //require_once 'PEAR.php';
require_once __DIR__."/Socket.php";
```

Comment: If you are using a linux system, don't forget that files are case sensitive.  Net/smtp.php is a different file than Net/SMTP.php.  I note this because the error you got had the filename in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Your include path is not setup correctly.

You need to have the pear base directory configured as part of the `include_path` in your php.ini.
I guess that you got a new php.ini with php 8.1, which does not contain the modifications of the previous php version's php.ini.

The base directory is that directory in which the "Net" folder (that contains SMTP.php) resides in.